# unable to run server, I think it is because I have 2 applications using the same port?

Tags: express

Just Curious (I solved this problem by just using a different port but the issue still triggers me), When I am trying to run the following code:

```
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "30mb", exteded: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }));
app.use(cors());

const CONNECTION_URL = <correct MongoDB connection url>

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

mongoose.connect(CONNECTION_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
    .then(() => 
    app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port`+PORT))
).catch((error) => console.log(error.message));
```

I keep getting an error thrown in my console:

```
{   code: 'EADDRINUSE',   errno: -48,   syscall: 'listen',   address: '::',   port: 5000 }
```

so after surfing through countless numbers of resources, they all essentially said I had to applications using the same port 5000? So I followed the "solutions" to the problem which all seemed to be killing the Port.

Firstly, I ran:

```
netstat -avtn | egrep 'Proto|5000'
```

To get:

```
Foreign Address        (state)     rhiwat shiwat    pid   epid  state    options
tcp6       0      0  *.5000                 *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072   1883      0 0x0100 0x00000006
tcp4       0      0  *.5000                 *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072   1883      0 0x0100 0x00000006
```

then I tried a few different commands to try and kill.
1) `kill -9 $(lsof -t -i:5000)`
2) `kill <the appropriate pid>`
3) `kill -9 <the appropriate pid>`

However, none of the solutions seemed to work. I even tried the famous computer off and on solution and closed all my applictions but they didn't work either. Does anyone know how I could have solved this without changing my port number?

Answer (score 0):

Two different applications/processes cannot run on the same port. You will need to use different ports to use them parallelly.

Based on your OS there are tons of resources online to kill a process running on a specific port. The process/commands are similar to the ones you have listed to kill a process on a port.